# Drush: Watchdog search explained

Tags: drush, log-messages

Can somebody explain how watchdog searching works? I can never get it to locate the log entries I'm looking for.

Let's say I have the following watchdog entries:

```
476722  10/Jun 10:31  notice    content  page: updated Protective Factors in Elementary School.
476723  10/Jun 10:31  notice    php      Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in _menu_translate() (line 777 of /var/www/html/domainnamehere/includes/menu.inc).
476724  10/Jun 10:40  notice    content  page: updated School/District Administrators.
476725  10/Jun 10:42  notice    content  page: updated Teachers.
476726  10/Jun 10:42  notice    php      Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in _menu_translate() (line 777 of /var/www/html/domainnamehere/includes/menu.inc).
```

All of following return "No log messages available":

```
drush wd-show "Undefined offset"
drush wd-show "%Undefined offset%"
drush wd-show "menu_translate"
```

If I want to find all of the "Undefined offset" watchdog entries, what Drush command do I have to run?

Comment: Your commands are valid, but you had initially used `ws-show`, which I assumed was a typo. Is there a chance that you were trying `drush ws-show`?

Comment: yes, 'ws-show' was a typo.

Comment: hmm..as an FYI, this seems to be the case with any PHP errors in the Watchdog logs.

Comment: Interesting. It does seems to work with other error types, even custom ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just pass the [stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) from Drush as the [stdin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) to [`grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep).

Example:

```
drush wd-show | grep 'Undefined offset'
```

**As a bonus** - If you want the errors in a file, try the following:

```
drush wd-show | grep 'Undefined offset' > ~/Undefined-errors.txt
```

This'll put the errors into a text file in your home directory :-)

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind but gets the job done.

Comment: The only caveat would be that you have to add the -count modifier. wd-show is only includes the last 10 entries.

Also, I don't believe this would translate into wd-delete.

The matching functionality is OOTB Watchdog functionality, the question is... why doesn't it work the way the documentation states?

Comment: If you want it to work with `wd-delete` something like the following would work: `drush wd-show | awk '{print $1}' | xargs drush wd-delete`.  However, you are right and it should just work.  I've tested the command with other errors from the watchdog logs and it works fine, but I don't have any sites quickly to hand that have any PHP errors in them.

Comment: Actually that last command won't work at all because of the `Id` line in the first column :(

Comment: @Chapabu answered the question correctly and succinctly even though I was hoping for a different response. :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually I wrote this feature for drush. Didn't realize this problem untill now.

The explanation: the watchdog message is stored as a text with variables that are replaced by using the t() function. OTOH drush wd search functionality is based on a database query.

That's the output you get:

```
# drush wd-show --type=php

 ID  Date          Type      Severity  Message                                                                   
 95  20/Jun 22:28  php       notice    Notice: Undefined variable: output in mothership_item_list() (line 304 of 
 94  20/Jun 22:27  php       notice    Notice: Undefined variable: output in mothership_item_list() (line 304 of 
 93  20/Jun 22:26  php       notice    Notice: Undefined variable: output in mothership_item_list() (line 304 of 
 91  20/Jun 22:26  php       notice    Notice: Undefined variable: output in mothership_item_list() (line 304 of 
 89  20/Jun 22:26  php       notice    Notice: Undefined variable: output in mothership_item_list() (line 304 of 
 88  20/Jun 22:26  php       notice    Notice: Undefined variable: output in mothership_item_list() (line 304 of 
 87  20/Jun 22:26  php       notice    Notice: Undefined variable: output in mothership_item_list() (line 304 of 
 86  20/Jun 22:26  php       notice    Notice: Undefined variable: output in mothership_item_list() (line 304 of 
 85  20/Jun 22:26  php       notice    Notice: Undefined variable: output in mothership_item_list() (line 304 of 
 84  20/Jun 22:26  php       notice    Notice: Undefined variable: output in mothership_item_list() (line 304 of
```

But that's the database content:

```
# drush sql-query "SELECT wid,message FROM watchdog WHERE type='php' LIMIT 10"

wid message
27  %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).
59  %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).
60  %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).
61  %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).
62  %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).
63  %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).
64  %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).
66  %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).
67  %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).
68  %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).
```

It doesn't seem there's an accurate fix for this. Drush could try to do its best on searching by filtering also by the 'variables' column of the watchdog table though.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation; this makes sense as to why I can't search for individual php errors.